# Stay in same page when form is not submitted

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the following form

```
 <form id="postForm" action="post.php" method="post">
```

and a post.php file. Both of them are working properly. I just need to make sure that when I check the checkbox the form is submitted and when I don't, it should stay on the same page.I found a few tutorials using jquery and ajax, but I was required to use Javascript. Can anyone help, thank you in advanced

```
function validate() {       
    if(document.getElementById('postTW').checked){
        document.getElementById("postForm").submit();
    }
    else{   
    }    
}
```

Comment: you want to submit from php?

Comment: @RakeshSharma I want to submit the form using javascript. If the checkbox is checked the form should be submitted and it should execute the php files. Otherwise, it should stay on the same page